# Alert message repeated on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an Alert System that would let the user know that they have let a field empty. If one field is left empty and the next button is pressed an alert comes up, if the same field is left empty again and the button is pressed (2 alerts will show up). The alerts keep increasing 3,4,5... etc. until all fields are complete. How can I make it so that only one Alert will show?

Leave the fields empty and press the "next button" in my code once, dismiss the alert and press the next button again. Dismiss the first alert, then you should see a second one. How can I prevent this from happening?

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click',
        function(){
            //text inputs
            if(!document.getElementById('fullname').value){
                alert('Full Name is required');
                return false;
            }

            else if(!document.getElementById('email').value){
                alert('Email is required');
                return false;
            }

            else if(!document.getElementById('phone').value){
                alert('Phone Number is required');
                return false;
            }

            else if(!document.getElementById('age').value){
                alert('Age is required');
                return false;
            }

            //radio buttons
            var genderSet = false;
            var genderBtns = document.getElementsByName('gender');
            //console.log(genderBtns);
            for(var i = 0, btn; btn = genderBtns[i];++i){
                if(btn.checked){
                    genderSet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!genderSet){
                alert('Gender is required');
                return false
            }

            if(animating) return false;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
                step: function(now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50)+"%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
                    next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function(){
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
            });
        });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Background Information</h3>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">

    <h4>Gender</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender-male"/>
            <label for="gender-male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender-female"/>
            <label for="gender-female">Female</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="terms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" id="btnNext" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: _"How can i make it so that only one Alert will show?"_ Don't put an alert in every if condition?

Comment: What would be the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snippet**

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
    //text inputs
    if (!document.getElementById('fullname').value) {
        alert('Full Name is required');
        return false;
    } else if (!document.getElementById('email').value) {
        alert('Email is required');
        return false;
    } else if (!document.getElementById('phone').value) {
        alert('Phone Number is required');
        return false;
    } else if (!document.getElementById('age').value) {
        alert('Age is required');
        return false;
    }

    //radio buttons
    var genderSet = false;
    var genderBtns = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    //console.log(genderBtns);
    for (var i = 0, btn; btn = genderBtns[i]; ++i) {
        if (btn.checked) {
            genderSet = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!genderSet) {
        alert('Gender is required');
        return false
    }

    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50) + "%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
            });
            next_fs.css({
                'left': left,
                'opacity': opacity
            });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
                'left': left
            });
            previous_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                'opacity': opacity
            });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Background Information</h3>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">

    <h4>Gender</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender-male" />
            <label for="gender-male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender-female" />
            <label for="gender-female">Female</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="terms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" id="btnNext" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Remove your event listener `document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click',function)`. On every click of next button its adding another click event to same button. That's why you are getting multiple alert.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

Use on of the tow event that you attach for the same element. See bellow events are for the same button.

```
 $(".next").click(function(){
 document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click',
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined two event listeners. The second event listener is added to a list of listeners in memory. Each time the button is clicked, a new event listener for the `btnNext` is created, causing the event listener to be called for each time that you press the button. Change your code to the following.

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){

//text inputs
if(!document.getElementById('fullname').value){
alert('Full Name is required');
return false;
}

else if(!document.getElementById('email').value){
alert('Email is required');
return false;
}

else if(!document.getElementById('phone').value){
alert('Phone Number is required');
return false;
}

else if(!document.getElementById('age').value){
alert('Age is required');
return false;
}
        
//radio buttons
var genderSet = false;
var genderBtns = document.getElementsByName('gender');
//console.log(genderBtns);
for(var i=0, btn; btn=genderBtns[i];++i){
if(btn.checked){
  genderSet=true;
  break;
 }
 }
 if(!genderSet){
 alert('Gender is required');
 return false
 } 
      
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
     
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- fieldsets -->
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Background Information</h3>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">
        
        <h4>Gender</h4>
        <div class="row">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender-male"/>
          <label for="gender-male">Male</label>
        </div> 
          <div>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender-female"/>
          <label for="gender-female">Female</label>
        </div>
            
    </div>
        <div class="row">
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="terms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. </label>
      </div>
    </div>

<input type="button" name="next" id="btnNext" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
```